# how to delete broadcast message after read it by my app?

Tags: android, sms, android-broadcast

I read a broadcast sms in my app.

I want to  first check a specific pattern exist or not in that message. If not exist then I want to delete that sms without saving it in inbox folder.

I am able to read sms successfully in my app but unable to delete it. Code snippet as below.

```
public class SmsListener extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (Telephony.Sms.Intents.SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            for (SmsMessage smsMessage : Telephony.Sms.Intents.getMessagesFromIntent(intent)) {
                String  messageBody = smsMessage.getMessageBody();
                String pattern="$Ntmds";
                if(messageBody.indexOf(pattern)!=-1){
                    Log.d("sdsd,", String.valueOf(messageBody));
                }else {
                    //i want to delete here
                   // abortBroadcast(); <-- this is nnot working for me
                    Log.d("vb,", String.valueOf(messageBody));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
 <receiver android:name=".SmsListener">
        <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647">
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

I tried a lot but not getting any success. I used by **abortBroadcast()**  but its also not work for me. please help me.

Comment: which android version you are using?

Comment: i used  6.0 (marshmallow).

Comment: You shouldn't be using normal SMS for this-  use port based SMS, so it never is seen in the general inbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do it on Marshmallow. it will only work with Android OS <= 4.3

With the release of Android 4.4 KitKat (API level 19), the option to block an SMS message and prevent it from being delivered to the default SMS app has been removed. Non-default SMS app's may observe SMS messages as they are received, but any attempt to abort the broadcast will be ignored by Android 4.4+.

If you have an existing app which relies on aborting SMS message broadcasts then you may want to consider the impact this change in behaviour will have when your users upgrade to Android 4.4+.

http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html

Comment: it means there is no way to abort that sms?

Comment: You have 2 other ways which may solve your problem

Follow Google advice on how to request the user to switch the default SMS application to your application during the time when you need to perform your changes (and once you finish doing it, allow the user to switch back to the original default SMS app).
or     Find a temporary hacky way to do what you need to do. As a hint, there is a hidden API: AppOpsManager that you could potentially exploit in order to give your application write permissions (OP_WRITE_SMS), head over to this XDA page to learn more about it: